# Dynamically adding airflow tasks on the basis of DB return value

Tags: airflow

I want to fetch value from DB and run tasks in parallel for each value. Additional/less values can be returned by DB in each call.

```
def values_from_db():
     # fetch data from DB. sample value - ["val1", "val2", "val3"]
     return values

for val in values_from_db():
     task1(val) >> task2(val)
```

`values_from_db` method will be called a lot of times to capture changes in the DAG file.

Is there any better approach to handle this - like calling `values_from_db` in the first task and then adding tasks dynamically on the basis of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dev, this seems like a reasonable approach. So long as the values remain relatively static and your DAG configuration reasonably accounts for potential  changes.

There are plenty use cases in projects I'm aware of where the configuration for Tasks / DAGs has been provided in yaml or similar as part of the project. Conceptually, what you are proposing is not too dissimilar.

Do note, that there is some overheads with your approach here. Firstly, that your database call will be invoked by the Scheduler on every heartbeat.  Which could prove problematic if the values change in terms of number or any change at all while the DAG is in a running state.

One alternative I might encourage is that you group the returned values and distribute them evenly to tasks beneath them. Such that you have a task for the first 10% of the values etc. That will save a lot of issues that could be introduced from "change" on the db side.

Comment: A lot of db call invoked by the Scheduler seems overkill in my solution. If I run this as the first step and push its return value in xcom,  I am wondering if I can access that value somehow in the main DAG file.